# How to retrieve a list of messages from a channel

Tags: c#, discord.net

I'm working on a Discord bot and I want to edit a previously posted message by the bot. I'm storing the message id to SQL database and then retrieving it.

The message is correctly found however the message is currently stored as `IMessage` and to use `ModifyAsync` i believe it needs to be `SocketUserMessage` so i am now using the below line of code however the variable `EditMessage` isn't being set.

Convert the variable `message` to `SocketUserMessage`

```
var EditMessage = message as SocketUserMessage;
```

```
while (reader.Read())
{
     ulong MessageID = (ulong)reader.GetInt64(0);                     
     var message = await Context.Channel.GetMessageAsync(MessageID);
     var EditMessage = message as SocketUserMessage;
     await EditMessage.ModifyAsync(x => x.Content = "Test [Edited].");
}
```

Getting error:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Which will because the value of `EditMessage`is Null

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: You have to [get the message](https://docs.stillu.cc/api/Discord.WebSocket.SocketTextChannel.html#Discord_WebSocket_SocketTextChannel_GetMessageAsync_System_UInt64_Discord_RequestOptions_) first. You can't expect the message to magically appear with just an ID.

Comment: That is why ive come here, I've asked how to retrieve messages first as i can't do it with just an ID....

Comment: In the link above, it showed you how.

Comment: Apologies, the link wasn't showing on mobile,  ill give this GetMessageAsync another go, i did try using this already and GetMessagesAsync

Comment: i've done some further work on this and from your advise got `GetMessageAsync` included but i'm stuck on the conversion of `IMessage` to `SocketUserMessage` i believe

Comment: The downloaded messages are of type `RestUserMessage`; REST entities and WS ones are not interchangeable. You likely do not need them to be in WS anyways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the comments recieved I've got this working

Anyone who struggles with this in future here's how i did it

```
while (reader.Read())
    {                       
       ulong MessageID = (ulong)reader.GetInt64(0);                     
       var message = (RestUserMessage)await Context.Channel.GetMessageAsync(MessageID);
       await message.ModifyAsync(x => x.Content = "Test [Edited].");
    }
```